# terraform invalid or unknown key: lifecycle_rule

Tags: terraform

While running `terraform plan` I got the error:

`* aws_s3_bucket.myBucketName: : invalid or unknown key: lifecycle_rule`

I am using Terraform v0.6.12

Answer (score 1):

According to the changelog, you need >= 0.6.15 (April 22, 2016)

provider/aws: Add support S3 Bucket Lifecycle Rule (#6220)
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0615-april-22-2016